# How to write a dynamic css to parameterize a matching text Selenium Java

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am working on a new application filled with Shadow-roots. So before shadow roots I can use Xpath but Once I am in the shadow root I have to use CSS selector. Below is the Root tree

[image]

I want to write a css So I can match the exact button name like

`div[text='Introduction']`

Is it possible ? If possible what would be the the CSS selector to match the button name.

As in a left navigation panel there are multiples buttons (Introduction, Summery, Reports) I want to write a CSS selector and parameterize them with just button text. So that using one CSS selector I can click on all the button just by passing the button text.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to use only CSS selectors inside of a shadow-root. You are free to use whatever locators you want.

Also, there is no way to locate an element by contained text using a CSS selector.

Comment: I don't think we can use xpath or any other locator to interact any element present in shadow dom. The only was i found is to use css after i enter into that shadow dom or to use javascript exec. But the issue is after I enter into the shadow dom that element only have a text. And using css we dont have a way to use text.

Comment: I've used XPath and CSS selectors inside the shadow dom so I know it's possible.